# Carousel ruins navbar if I remove padding from it (Bootstrap framework)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my carousel to appear immediately after my navbar but if I remove padding from carousel it appears after my navbar but the navbar stretches far from view in mobile view

```
<div class="container-fluid m-t-3 p-x-0 "> //Code with padding so it appears under navbar

<div class="container-fluid "> //When I remove margin and padding the navbar stretches too far in mobile view
```

[Navbar on mobile view when I remove padding from carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG0XX.png)

[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/Agonn/pen/oLKVzQ)

Commented the parts that I'm trying to fix and the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class img-responsive to the parent element of the images in the carousel or to each image in the carousel, this will allow them shrink along with the window size. I added this to your code in code pen at line 63:

```
<div class="carousel-item active randomize img-responsive">

                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/500" alt="First slide ">
                        <div class="carousel-caption hidden-md-down">
                            <h3>Sedefi</h3>
                            <p>webpage 1</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item img-rounded">
                        <img src="http://placecorgi.com/700/500?index=random" alt="Second slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption hidden-md-down">
                            <h3>Sedefi</h3>
                            <p>webpage 2</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="http://placecorgi.com/700/500?index=random" alt="Third slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption hidden-md-down">
                            <h3>Sedefi</h3>
                            <p>webpage 3</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

You can read more about styling images with bootsrap [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images)

And here is what it looks like when you use a smaller dislpay:
[image]

Comment: Thank you mate ,I didn't know that was the issue,mind tell me how you troubleshooted it?

Comment: I been using Bootsrap for a while now. I went to your codepen link, and added the random images, when I started resizing the screen I noticed the images were not behaving accordingly, so I checked which bootsrap classes you were using and found out you were missing img-responsive.
Some things you only learn by reading, trying and fixing.

Comment: By the way, if the answer was helpful I would appreciate a vote up. 
If it solves you question please make it the accepted answer, I could use the privileges of being able to comment on other people posts. Thanks @Nex

Comment: Thank you mate ,I appreciate it.